# Can Someone say what actually "Platform" means?

Tags: c, operating-system, embedded, platform

I am new to embedded and I am confused with this word
"Platform" whether it specifies about the 'board' or 'Operating system'?
For example, some says like, "I am working on windows platform" and some says like "The platform I am using is Raspberry Pi" etc.
I know this is a silly or stupid question for many but if you need to block this question, kindly do it after some answers.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers.Still I am little confused, one straight question: I am working on LPC4330  ARM  board with Linux OS on it So if some one asks "In  what platform you are working or using in your project?" what  should I answer? Linux or LPC4330 ARM

Comment: Both.  Your hardware platform is the LPC..., and the software platform is Linux.  Combined, it's "Linux on an LPC4330..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term platform varies with the context.

Platform can be windows or linux for application software developers.

It can be 32-bit,64-bit,Intel,AMD etc. for OS,Driver and firmware developers.(Based on CPU architecture)

For Embedded systems platform is mostly used to refer processors architecture.

There are many other terms you will encounter,those are based underlying technology.

Answer (score 2):

The term **platform** is used to denote any collection of software, services and resources that, within a specific context, are considered a given so they can be used as building blocks for application software (or to build a higher level platform on top of that - something considered a platform in another context)

refer the awesome answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2035185/3164682)

Answer (score 2):

The term "platform" is a buzzword. It can mean anything that you want it to mean. I maintained a corporate strategy document in which the term "platform" was used for a myriad of purposes. All the answers above are correct. We used "platform" for all the above and more.

Comment: I think this is the most correct answer. To ponder the deeper meaning of buzzwords is generally not a meaningful exercise.

Answer (score 0):

A **platform** is an underlying computer system on which application programs can run.
We can also call it a group of technologies that are used as a base upon which other applications, processes or technologies are developed.

The “IT” definition of a platform is very similar to the traditional one – It is a **foundation software system** which **supports and provides services** to other programs.  Those programs are said to be “**built upon**” the foundation software or “**platform**”.  That supported application may well be a platform for another application and so on up the line.

Answer (score 0):

> **Defination:**
>
> "Platform is actually a **group** of technologies that are used as a
> base upon which other applications, processes or technologies are
> developed."

So, The question you were asking was ***whether platform specifies about the 'board' or 'Operating system'***

Always remember that term platform specifies both *hardware(board)* **and** *software(OS)* as its definition says that it is **group** of at are used as a base upon which other applications, processes or technologies are developed.

So, If someone asks, which platform you are designing you your solution for? or which platform you are working on? Answer can't be only I am working on Raspberry Pi or I am working on Windows.

Rather the answer must be I am working *for* Windows *on* Raspberry Pi or my solution will be *for* Windows *on* Raspberry Pi. That means, the answer must include both ***on which hardware and for what Operating System (software)*** as if refers to group of technologies.

I hope that this explanation will help you a bit in clarifying your concept.